# SetInterval doesn't same when called again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm making a simple program which increases a number incrementally for every 0.5 second. When I click start it works perfectly. But when I click restart, the increments go fine, but they don't increment every 0.5 sec and go pretty fast, and this happens when I am calling the same function? JS fiddle link below.

function runFunc(){

Comment: The `setInterval()` function returns the value you need to pass to `clearInterval()`. Passing the function reference does nothing.

Comment: @Pointy I am sorry, I didn't understand. I am more a newbie to JS.

Comment: You're passing `varName` to `clearInterval()`, and that won't work.

Comment: @Pointy, I tried without it as well, its the same, the increments just fly off pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable interval outside function

```
var myInterval = null;
```

check if an interval is already running if yes clear it in order to avoid multiple interval running the same function which makes the interval became looks faster than the first time it's called

```
if (myInterval != null) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

also this is not correct

```
clearInterval(varName);
```

the parameter should be an interval which is like this

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

so your javascript code would be like this

```
var myInterval = null;

function runFunc(){
    $('#counter').val(zero);
    var varName = function(){
        var number = Number($('#number').val());
        var counter = Number($('#counter').val());
        if(counter < number) {
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
            $('#counter').val(counter);
        } else {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    };
    //check if an interval is already running if yes clear it
    if (myInterval != null) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
    myInterval = setInterval(varName, 500);
};

show.click(runFunc);

reset.click(function(){
    $('#number').val(zero);
    $('#counter').val(zero);
});

restart.click(runFunc);
```

Comment: The argument to `clearInterval()` needs to be `myInterval` in both places where it's called.

Comment: @Pointy okay noted. also I forgot it's just the questioner mistake which I forgot to correct

Answer (score 0):

u have to Declare a Variable for setInterval like "setIntervalID"

so stop it clearInterval("setIntervalID");

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u9pxye30/)

```
var initialNumber = 10;
var zero = 0;
$('#number').val(initialNumber);
$('#counter').val(zero);
var show = $('#show');
var reset = $('#reset');
var restart = $('#restart');
var setIntervalID;
// console.log('initial value of number is ' + number);
// console.log(typeof number);
// console.log('initial value of counter is ' + counter);

var varName = function(){
        var number = Number($('#number').val());
        var counter = Number($('#counter').val());
        if(counter < number) {
            counter++;
            console.log(counter);
            $('#counter').val(counter);
        } 
    }

function runFunc(){
        $('#counter').val(zero);
        setIntervalID = setInterval(varName, 500);
};
function stopFunc(){
  clearInterval(setIntervalID);
};

function restartGO(){

stopFunc();
runFunc();
}

show.click(runFunc);
restart.click(restartGO);

reset.click(function(){
    $('#number').val(zero);
    $('#counter').val(zero);
});
```